# I want a live plot line instead of a series of dots using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

This program works fine but the live plot shows a series of dots. I'd rather see a line connecting the dots or simply a line. Below, after the # is what I already tried that didn't work.

```
import time, serial, sys
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
serPort = 'COM5'
dataFile=open("loggedData.dat", "w");
ser =serial.Serial(serPort, 9600)
sys.stdout.flush()
#plt.setp(lines,'color','r','linewidth',2.0)
fig=plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.show()
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    print line;
    p=line.split(' ')
    dataFile.write(line)
    #plt.setp(line,'color','r','linewidth',2.0)
    #plt.plot((p[0]), (p[1]), 'drawstyle', '-')
    #plt.plot((p[0]), (p[1]), '-')
    plt.plot((p[0]), (p[1]), 'ro')
    plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to keep track of the previous point, so that Matplotlib can draw a line between two points.

```
prev = None
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    print line;
    p=line.split(' ')
    dataFile.write(line)
    if prev is not None:
        plt.plot((prev[0], p[0]), (prev[1], p[1]), 'r')  # draw the line
        plt.plot((p[0]), (p[1]), 'ro')  # draw the dot
    prev = (p[0], p[1])
    plt.draw()
```

Btw, I am not sure if your code is actually doing what you want.
 `p=line.split(' ')` gives you a list of strings that you pass to the plot function. You probably want to convert them to numbers instead: `p = [float(i) for i in line.split(' ')`.